# Dependency of probability of sum of i.i.d exponential random variables for $l$ and $l+1$ samples

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We draw $l$ samples from an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. We know that summation of those samples, $Y = \sum_{i=1}^{l} X_i$ is less than a threshold, $t$. If we draw one more sample and add it to previous samples, $Z = Y + X_{l+1}$, what is the probability that the new summation of is greater than $t$? $P(Z>t|Y\leq t)$ ?

Samples are i.i.d.
I know that sum of $l$ i.i.d. exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda$ has Erlang distribution with parameter $\lambda$ and shape $l$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

You are asking what is $\mathbb{P}[X>t - Y|Y \le t]$ when $X,Y$ are independent with their distributions known? Note
$$
\mathbb{P}[A|B] = \frac{\mathbb{P}[A \cap B]}{\mathbb{P}[B]}
$$
and the denominator in your case is a 1-distribution problem, whereas the numerator is a double integral...

**UPDATE**

Further note that
$$
\mathbb{P}[X>t - Y \cap Y \le t]
= \int_{y=-\infty}^{y=t} \int_{x=t-y}^{x=\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy
$$
and since $X$ and $Y$ are independent,
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x) f_Y(y),
$$
so the integral becomes
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{P}[X>t - Y \cap Y \le t]
&= \int_{y=-\infty}^{y=t}
          f_Y(y)
           \left(\int_{x=t-y}^{x=\infty} f_X(x) dx\right)dy \\
&= \int_{y=-\infty}^{y=t} f_Y(y) \left(1 - F_X(t-y)\right)dy \\
&= F_Y(t) - \int_{y=-\infty}^{y=t} f_Y(y) F_X(t-y) dy
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I just can't understand the part about double integral. Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: I mean how to derive distribution of [$A \cap B$]

Comment: @Yashar see the update

Comment: Now I got it, thanks!